Cookie settings for local development (from React to Nest)
I am trying to create an authentication system using sessions (with @fastify/secure-session). The problem I encountered is that when the frontend hosted on "localhost:3200" sends a request to the /auth endpoint served on "localhost:3000", the cookie is sent back successfully in the auth response with the necessary information. However, the cookie is not stored in the browser. Therefore, for the next request from the frontend to an /isLogged endpoint, the session cookie is not included.
The cookie configuration on the backend (on localhost:3000) :
  cookie: {
      path: '/',
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: +process.env.SESSION_MAX_AGE,
      sameSite: (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") ? 'none' : 'lax',
      secure: (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") ? true : false
  }

The fetch request from the frontend (from localhost:3200) :
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/admins/auth/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
  });


I'm not sure if you can use httpOnly: true with JS, since I believe cookies are then not stored correctly/accessible by javascript.
